# This property cannot be set after a connection has been opened

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I'm trying to connect to Oracle through .NET Core following this docs:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3/odpnt/InstallCoreConfiguration.html#GUID-24C963AE-F20B-44B5-800C-594CA06BD24B

But I'm facing this error:

> This property cannot be set after a connection has been opened
> System.InvalidOperationException: This property cannot be set after a
> connection has been opened    at
> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataSourceCollection.Add(String
> tnsName, String tnsDescriptor)    at
> Infrastructure.Persistence.Factory.ConnectionFactory.SetupOracleConnection()
> in
> C:\Users\WINDOWS\RiderProjects\TicketsAPI\Infrastructure\Persistence\Factory\ConnectionFactory.cs:line
> 22

I don't have clue why this is happening, there's my ConnectionFactory:

```
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

namespace Infrastructure.Persistence.Factory;

public class ConnectionFactory : IConnectionFactory
{
private const string TnsName = "ORCL";
private readonly ILogger<ConnectionFactory> _logger;

public ConnectionFactory(ILogger<ConnectionFactory> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

public IDbConnection? Connection => SetupOracleConnection();

private OracleConnection? SetupOracleConnection()
{
    OracleConfiguration.OracleDataSources.Add(TnsName,
        "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-FP8GDE4)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))"); // <-- This is the line 22 mentioned in the StackTrace 
    
    . . . //Some configs that are in the doc file.
    OracleConnection oracleConnection = null!;
    try
    {
        oracleConnection = new OracleConnection($"user id=kevinadmin; password=1234; data source={TnsName}");
        oracleConnection.Open();
        return oracleConnection;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError("An error occurred while trying to connect to database {EMessage}", e.Message);
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        oracleConnection?.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How many times do you want `OracleConfiguration.OracleDataSources.Add()` to run over the course of your application?

Comment: I want that Add method just run once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit:
I may have misunderstood the issue.  If the exception is happening on second and subsequent calls to `Connection`, then this answer might apply]

By declaring your property like

```cs
public IDbConnection? Connection => SetupOracleConnection();
```

you're instructing the `{ get; }` (which is what the `=>` is sugar for) to execute the `SetupOracleConnection()` every time it is accessed.

You should try to encapsulate that into a singleton instance.

```cs
private IDbConnection? _connection = null;
public IDbConnection? Connection => _connection ?? ( _connection = SetupOracleConnection());
```

Comment: Yup, I forgot that => is the same as calling get method. Ty.